# Load graphql content when scrolling

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, graphql-js

How I can load graphql content when user is scrolling? Cause I have like 10.000 records and I don't want to render them all. I want to show like only 80 and render more when scrolling.
Here is a code:

```
<Query query={ALL_BOT_ITEMS_QUERY}>
 {({loading, error, data}) => {
    if(loading) return <div className="preloader show"></div>
    if(error) return <p>Error: {error}</p>

    return (
      <Scrollbars style={{height: '570px'}}>
        {data.allBotItems.map(item => {
          if(this.props.bot.choosenItemsIds.indexOf(item.id) === -1) {
            return <Item key={item.id} item={item} conditions={this.state.conditions} side='bot' />
          }
        })}
      </Scrollbars>
    )
  }}
</Query>
```

Comment: What is `Scrollbars` ?

Comment: @AndyRay, It is an React library called 'react-custom-scrollbars'

Comment: Are you still fetching all records at once and just want to limit how many you render, or do you want to only fetch a chunk of items at a time and fetch additional ones as the user scrolls down? If it's the latter, does the query you're fetching support pagination?

Comment: @DanielRearden, hmmm... GraphQL doesn't support pagination, but I can easily add it passing page to my query and process it at the server

Comment: @MIkle graphql absolutely supports pagination. It's even built into the spec. https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/

Comment: @MatthewHerbst, never seen it. Thank's. But that doesn't solve the problem with rendering when scrolling

Comment: Well, do you want to only render the items in the view, or do you just want to lazy load/render new items on scroll?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst. render new items on scroll

Comment: Hard to beat the docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/pagination.html

Comment: @MatthewHerbst For me this is more like just example rather a part of grapql spec. You still need to define all the fields in a schema.

Comment: @ArekJablonski that's true, and a good callout, thanks